# How to optimize huge queries?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, optimization

I have a CPU killing query which takes over 10secs to be executed:

```
select 
  sum(t.total) payment_amount, 
  sum(
    IFNULL(
      t.credit, group_wallets_transactions.credit
    )
  ) cashbacked_amount, 
  case when group_wallets_transactions.type = "daily_cashback"
         or group_wallets_transactions.type = "payment_consume" then "cashback"
       else group_wallets_transactions.type end type, 
  t.business_id as b_id, 
  business_sub_categories.name sub_category, 
  business_sub_categories.selected_img, 
  group_wallets_transactions.created_at as date, 
  businesses.shop_name 
from 
  `group_wallets_transactions` 
  left join (
    (
      select 
        'cash' as pay_type, 
        sum(amount) as total, 
        round(
          sum(daily_percentage * amount / 100), 
          2
        ) as credit, 
        DATE_ADD(
          Date(created_at), 
          INTERVAL 1 DAY
        ) as created_at, 
        `user_id`, 
        `business_id` 
      from 
        `pos_transactions` 
      where 
        (`user_id` = 408670) 
        and `rewarding_model` = 'cash' 
      group by 
        DATE_ADD(
          Date(created_at), 
          INTERVAL 1 DAY
        ), 
        `user_id`, 
        `business_id`
    ) 
    union all 
      (
        select 
          'credit' as pay_type, 
          sum(amount) as total, 
          round(
            sum(daily_percentage * amount / 100), 
            2
          ) as credit, 
          DATE_ADD(
            Date(created_at), 
            INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ) as created_at, 
          `user_id`, 
          `business_id` 
        from 
          `club_transactions` 
        where 
          (`user_id` = 408670) 
          and `customer_cashback_status` = 1 
          and `club_transactions`.`had_payment_reward` = 1 
          and `club_transactions`.`rewarding_model` = 'cash' 
          and `status` = 'paid' 
        group by 
          DATE_ADD(
            Date(created_at), 
            INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ), 
          `user_id`, 
          `business_id`
      )
  ) as `t` on date(
    group_wallets_transactions.created_at
  ) = date(t.created_at) 
  and `group_wallets_transactions`.`type` in ('daily_cashback') 
  left join `businesses` on `businesses`.`id` = `t`.`business_id` 
  left join `business_sub_categories` on `businesses`.`sub_category_id` = `business_sub_categories`.`id` 
where 
  (
    `group_wallets_transactions`.`user_id` = 408670
  ) 
group by 
  `type`, 
  `business_id`, 
  `sub_category`, 
  `selected_img`, 
  `date`, 
  `shop_name` 
order by 
  `group_wallets_transactions`.`created_at` desc
```

It works well and gives me the expected result. But since tables `pos_transactions` and `club_transactions` has become huge (each has about 1 million rows), now the execution time of the query above is over 10sec. Here is the result of `EXPLAIN`:

[image]

---

Also, `group_wallets_transactions` is not a `table`, it's a `view` and about 6sec of the execution time is just for running it, its logic is:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = `administrator` @`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `group_wallets_transactions` AS 
select 
  `wallets_transactions`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, 
  `wallets_transactions`.`type` AS `TYPE`, 
  cast(
    `wallets_transactions`.`created_at` as date
  ) AS `created_at`, 
  sum(
    `wallets_transactions`.`credit`
  ) AS `credit` 
from 
  `wallets_transactions` 
group by 
  `wallets_transactions`.`user_id`, 
  `wallets_transactions`.`type`, 
  cast(
    `wallets_transactions`.`created_at` as date
  )
```

**Any idea how can I optimize it?**

I've tried to put some composite indexes on needed columns and I made the performance better, but still, it takes 10sec to be executed and behaves like a bottleneck. Here is the result of `EXPLAIN` for the `group_wallets_transactions` view:

[image]

Comment: What's the data type of `wallets_transactions`.`created_at` and why are you casting it to `date`?

Comment: @TheImpaler It's currently `timestamp`, I'm casting it to `date` since I need to group the transactions of a user per day

Comment: You should definitively push down the predicate `user_id = 408670` to the view subquery. That means you may need to replace the view with its definition instead.

Comment: @TheImpaler I guess it's not possible to pass something for a `view` in MySQL. I did it for `stored procedure`s and `function`s, but never passed any argument for a `view`.

Comment: Ah, I got your point now. You meant I shouldn't use that `view` and use the logic inside the query

Comment: Yes, use the view definition instead -- enhanced with the filtering criteria `user_id = 408670` so it becomes really cheap to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Is `created_at` a `DATE`?  Or a `DATETIME`?  (If it is `DATE`, I can suggest a simplification that will speed up the query.)

Some indexes that may help:

```
group_wallets_transactions:  INDEX(user_id, type, created_at)
club_transactions:  INDEX(user_id)
pos_transactions:  INDEX(user_id, rewarding_model)
```

Please don't use

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(...created_at...) AS created_at
    ... GROUP BY DATE_ADD(...created_at...) ...
```

it is hard to know which `created_at` is being used.  Perhaps this is what you intended?

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(...created_at...) AS date_created
    ... GROUP BY date_created ...
```

Please qualify each column name with the table (or alias) that it comes from; I have probably left out some analysis because of not following what comes from where.

Looking at

```
SELECT  ....
        businesses.shop_name ...
    FROM ... (... GROUP BY ...) AS t
    LEFT JOIN  `businesses` AS b  ON b.`id` = `t`.`businesses_id`
    GROUP BY ...
```

I suggest rewriting to

```
SELECT  ...
        ( SELECT b.shot_name FROM businesses AS b
                  WHERE b.id = t.businesses_id ) AS show_name
    FROM (SELECT ...
        FROM ... (... GROUP BY ...) AS t
        GROUP BY ...
         ) AS t2
    ORDER BY ...
```

The former will repeatedly lookup `businesses.shop_name` before doing the GROUPing;   The latter will do it only once per business.  This *may* provide a significant speed-up.

Note the relative position of the 2nd `GROUP BY` versus `business_name`.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I will try your suggestions, upvoted